# drawRect method inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, drawrect, uibezierpath

I have a custom `UIView` inside `UIScrollView` with same size. And I am drawing `UIBezierPath` inside `UIView`s `drawRect` method. But when zooming changed in `UIScrollView` the `drawRect` method gets same rect always. So `UIBezierPath`s resolution is not refreshing. 
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement this scroll view delegate method to adjust the zoomable view's `contentScaleFactor` (what you are calling its "resolution"):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
                       withView:(UIView *)view
                        atScale:(float)scale {
    view.contentScaleFactor = scale * [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
}
```

You *might* also have to tell the view that it needs redrawing, but try it without first and see what happens.